# What category does a website fit under?

Tags: feature-request

I developed a mobile front end to StackOverflow... and I was wondering what category it fit under...

I mean, is it an app? Something else?

I think we need an additional category: **services**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No we don't. It is an app.

Simplicity is key to keep clutter at a minimum. The current two categorizations are perfect:

An **app** is something you make that utilizes the API to do something.

A **library** is something that provides an abstraction between an app and the API.

No need to invent a bunch of categorizations that aren't necessary.

Comment: That's kinda what I thought.